# Save file to Amazon S3 bucket in javascript

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a web app, frontend using HTML5 and Javascript, backend using Django.

In frontend, I want to save the uploaded photo in an Amazon S3 bucket in the javascript.

How could I achieve that？

I can access the Amazon S3 bucket using cyberduck now.

```
<script>
        function renderCover(value, row) {
            return '<img id="blah" alt="cover image" width="100" height="100" />\n' +
                '\n' +
                '<input type="file" \n' +
                '    onchange="document.getElementById(\'blah\').src = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0])">'
        }
</script>
```

Comment: You must send your image to back-end and there you can save it to S3, probably by using some sdk provided by amazon.

Comment: @NikitaMazur is correct, calling S3 API's such as this should be done from the Backend of your application and not the frontend. If you don't want to send files to the BE and then to S3, consider generating an S3 presigned URL that can be used to upload files to S3 directly from the client.

Comment: you can do better than send your image to back-end, you can request from backend the signed URL to put object and directly upload to s3 secure, so you won't waste your server resources. see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html

Answer (score 2):

Your code seems to be for download and show the image, not upload. You could use the [AWS SDK for javascript](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/). You probably are looking for something like [this AWS example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/s3-example-photo-album.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at my script at: https://github.com/TueNguyen2911/MealPlanAPI/blob/master/modules/img-upload.js

For uploading image to the S3 Bucket, you need 3 npm packages in the back-end not in the front-end:

- multer, it is a middleware to upload files
- multer-S3, it is a streaming multer storage engine for AWS S3, specify it in the `storage` option of `multer`
- aws-sdk, javascript libraries for AWS services

After setting up and configuring all the options for multer, multer-s3, aws-sdk. Simply call the multer's function. For example: `upload.single(filename)`